# My search controller broke without errors and won't display accordingly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I have this in search/index:

```
<%= form_tag search_index_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :title, params[:title], placeholder: "title" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :content, params[:content], placeholder: "content" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>
<div class="section">
  <div class=content>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <%= post.title %>
      <%= post.content %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div
```

And this is my search controller:

```
content_term = params[:content]
title_term = params[:title]

if content_term
  @posts = Post.where('content LIKE ?', "%#{content_term}%")
else
  @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
end

if title_term
  @posts = Post.where('title LIKE ?', "%#{title_term}%")
else
  @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
end

if content_term != 0 and title_term != 0
  @posts = Post.search(content_term, title_term)
else
  @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

It doesn't work with either term on their own nor both terms together.

This is the .search method from the Post.rb:

```
def self.search(content_term, title_term)
  return scoped unless content_term.present? || title_term.present?
  where(['content LIKE ? AND title LIKE ?', "%#{content_term}%", "%#{title_term}%"]) 
end
```

It loads up fine, so the url to search_index_path works fine in the routes but it's something about :gets and :posts or bonus data types that I don't seem to know.

As you can see the params are connected between the controller and the view, and follow through the controller into the SQL, but it won't return posts.

Server logs:

```
Started GET "/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&content=ods" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-04 08:10:57 +1100
Processing by SearchController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "title"=>"", "content"=>"ods"}
  User Load (3.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/adenhandasyde/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ /Users/adenhandasyde/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Ahoy::Visit Create (9.0ms)  INSERT INTO "ahoy_visits" ("visit_token", "visitor_token", "user_id", "ip", "user_agent", "referrer", "referring_domain", "landing_page", "browser", "os", "device_type", "started_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["visit_token", "fb09791e-c1a1-4fbf-8ef2-1f97d4690d74"], ["visitor_token", "f460dc00-5027-4b60-8c17-5550bbc8905a"], ["user_id", 1], ["ip", "127.0.0.1"], ["user_agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36"], ["referrer", "http://0.0.0.0:3000/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&content=ods"], ["referring_domain", "0.0.0.0"], ["landing_page", "http://0.0.0.0:3000/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&content=ods"], ["browser", "Chrome"], ["os", "Mac"], ["device_type", "Desktop"], ["started_at", "2019-03-03 21:10:57.981414"]]
  ↳ /Users/adenhandasyde/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (2.2ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ /Users/adenhandasyde/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
[ActiveJob] [Ahoy::GeocodeV2Job] [92751e46-31db-4118-93b4-d3a8f54e8df7] Performing Ahoy::GeocodeV2Job (Job ID: 92751e46-31db-4118-93b4-d3a8f54e8df7) from Async(ahoy) with arguments: "fb09791e-c1a1-4fbf-8ef2-1f97d4690d74", "127.0.0.1"
[ActiveJob] Enqueued Ahoy::GeocodeV2Job (Job ID: 92751e46-31db-4118-93b4-d3a8f54e8df7) to Async(ahoy) with arguments: "fb09791e-c1a1-4fbf-8ef2-1f97d4690d74", "127.0.0.1"
[ActiveJob] [Ahoy::GeocodeV2Job] [92751e46-31db-4118-93b4-d3a8f54e8df7] Performed Ahoy::GeocodeV2Job (Job ID: 92751e46-31db-4118-93b4-d3a8f54e8df7) from Async(ahoy) in 5.7ms
  Rendering search/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (content LIKE '%ods%' AND title LIKE '%%')
  ↳ app/views/search/index.html.erb:11
  Rendered search/index.html.erb within layouts/application (10.5ms)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:41
  Ahoy::Event Create (6.9ms)  INSERT INTO "ahoy_events" ("visit_id", "user_id", "name", "properties", "time") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["visit_id", 2], ["user_id", 1], ["name", "Ran Action"], ["properties", "{\"controller\":\"search\",\"action\":\"index\"}"], ["time", "2019-03-03 21:10:58.343325"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:41
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:41
Completed 200 OK in 407ms (Views: 217.5ms | ActiveRecord: 33.9ms)
```

My bad, it works, the display was 800px down the page and I missed it.

Comment: Could you please add server log to the question?

Comment: @Vasilisa, Updated.

Comment: Looking to `SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (content LIKE '%ods%' AND title LIKE '%%')` line it works good. Does it return incorrect posts? Or how should it work in another words?

Comment: I tried it with "ods" and "how" with and without the pair, for ods and how in content and title in a post, and none of them came up with anything...

Comment: And you really have posts with "ods" in title and "how" in content? And it's not "Ods" or "How" in the post itself (first letter upcased)? Which db do you use? I'm asking so much because your controller code should work.